# hile trying to install rvm on ubuntu18.04 command keeps getting aborted

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

Like you can see under, once I type Y to continue installing, the terminal keeps aborting the command...

```
olivier@LAPTOP-LAJA56P3:~$ sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-8).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  autoconf autotools-dev libbison-dev libltdl-dev libltdl7 m4
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc gettext bison-doc libtool-doc ncurses-doc gfortran | fortran95-compiler gcj-jdk m4-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev bison libbison-dev libgdbm-dev libltdl-dev libltdl7 libncurses5-dev libtool m4
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
Need to get 2321 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9601 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Abort.
```

Does anyone can explain me this?

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid Interactive Input

You probably have a locale or keyboard mismatch of some kind. There's insufficient information in your post to diagnose that with any specificity, though. In the meantime, you can work around the problem by passing the `--yes` flag to *apt-get*, avoiding the need for interactive input.